# Unable to Open the dropdown of the DropDownPicker-React Native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, dropdown

I am new to React Native, I am trying to use the `DropDownPicker` present in the `react-native-dropdown-picker`, but I am unable to open dropdown to see the contents of the `DropDownPicker`, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.dropdownContainer}>
        /*this is the dropdown part*/
        <DropDownPicker  
            items={data} containerStyle={{height: 40}} 
            defaultValue={this.state.value} 
            placeholder={this.state.value}
            dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa', position: 'absolute'}} 
            onChangeItem={item=>this.setState({value: item.value})}/>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-native-dropdown-picker][1] - Latest version, (Functional Approach)

But I think it can be easily converted to a class based component.

Hope this helps !

```
export default function App() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState("apple");
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
            {label: 'Apple', value: 'apple'},
            {label: 'Banana', value: 'banana'}
    ]);

       return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
             <DropDownPicker
              open={open}
              containerStyle={{height: 40, backgroundColor:"red"}}
              value={value}
              items={items}
              setOpen={setOpen}
              setValue={setValue}
              setItems={setItems}
              />
         </View>
     </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```